# Questions about FB chatbot app review

Tags: facebook, bots, chatbot

I have an FB app ready for app review. That app provides basically a chatbot.

I have 2 questions:
1 - Can I set a webhook of a staging bot instance that is connected to a staging core system to which an FB user can authenticate using specific credentials. I ask this because I don't want to provide Production credentials to the FB reviewer.
2 - Can I provide the reviewer with a test FB page, or do I need to provide the final FB page?

In case of affirmative answers to both questions, when I set Production webhook URL and FB page, do I need to resubmit app review?

Thanks

Comment: You can change your webhook URL at any time, that doesn’t require review. And what page(s) you subscribe your bot to doesn’t either.

Comment: That's great! Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I set Production webhook URL and FB page, do I need to resubmit app review?

You can change your webhook URL at any time, that doesn’t require review. And what page(s) you subscribe your bot to doesn’t either.

---

Review is about the functionality your app provides, and how it uses the data it gets access to. Simply switching out the URL you receive the webhook request under, or which page(s) your bot is running on, is not relevant in that regard. That you switch from a test page to a live page after you got it successfully reviewed might rather be the norm than an exception. Plus, your bot can be used on multiple pages, so that you add others later on is also an expected use case.